# Quickbooks & Rails 5, can't create an invoice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, quickbooks-online

Things were working fine until I started the upgrade from Rails 4.2 to 5.0

Using qbo_api gem (1.8.1) which also now needs the simple_oauth (0.3.1) as well as the oauth (0.5.4) gem.  (The faraday gem (0.14.0) is loaded as another dependency.)

I can successfully do get requests for invoice, customer, etc., so the keys and initialization of the qbo_api object are all working for qbo_api.get() but when I try to create an invoice with qbo_api.create(:invoice, payload: ...), I get the error:

**Operation Could not find resource for relative : /v3/company/123145710499109/invoice of full path: https://sandbox.qbo.intuit.com/qbo50/v3/company/123145710499109/invoice is not supported.**

The same qbo_api object is working for get, I see nothing obviously wrong with the URL, and it is unreleated to the JSON payload.  I'm not sure where to look to debug this problem.

BTW, clicking on the URL above seems to go to QB just fine, returning a validation error as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be a problem in the 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 versions of the qbo_api gem.   Minimul has released version 1.8.2 which fixes this problem.

Kudos to Minimul for a quick response to this.

Answer (score 0):

check your realmId. Most probably realmId is not match to your connected intuit app. This is why its tells that Operation Could not find resource for relative.